# Splitting a file and its lines under Linux/bash

Tags: linux, bash, large-files, filesplitting

I have a rather large file (150 million lines of 10 chars). I need to split it in 150 files of 2 million lines, with each output line being alternatively the first 5 characters or the last 5 characters of the source line.
I could do this in Perl rather quickly, but I was wondering if there was an easy solution using bash.
Any ideas?

Comment: I think you need to be a bit clearer on what the transformation is exactly. (That is, I don't get it.) Perhaps a small example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Homework?  :-)

I would think that a simple pipe with sed (to split each line into two) and split (to split things up into multiple files) would be enough.

The man command is your friend.

---

Added after confirmation that it is not homework:

How about

```
sed 's/\(.....\)\(.....\)/\1\n\2/' input_file | split -l 2000000 - out-prefix-
```

?

Comment: Great! In the end I used this:
for file in *.txt; do echo $file;  sed 's/\(.....\)\(.....\)/\1\r\n\2/' $file | split -l 2000000 - $file.part.; done

Comment: this messed up formatting on a large csv file in the outputs, added new lines where there should't be any.

Answer (score 0):

I think that something like this could work:

```
out_file=1
out_pairs=0
cat $in_file | while read line; do
    if [ $out_pairs -gt 1000000 ]; then
        out_file=$(($out_file + 1))
        out_pairs=0
    fi
    echo "${line%?????}" >> out${out_file}
    echo "${line#?????}" >> out${out_file}
    out_pairs=$(($out_pairs + 1))
done
```

Not sure if it's simpler or more efficient than using Perl, though.

Answer (score 0):

First five chars of each line variant, assuming that the large file called x.txt, and assuming it's OK to create files in the current directory with names x.txt.* :

split -l 2000000 x.txt x.txt.out && (for splitfile in x.txt.out*; do outfile="${splitfile}.firstfive"; echo "$splitfile ->  $outfile"; cut -c 1-5 "$splitfile" > "$outfile"; done)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use native linux `split` function?

```
split -d -l 999999 input_filename
```

this will output new split files with file names like `x00 x01 x02...`

for more info see the manual

```
man split
```